# Null safety in dart (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, compile-time, dart-null-safety

Hello i know it is very common error in flutter when we deal with dart null safety. I have come to know why this error is occuring but i am unable to fix this error."Null check operator used on a null value" this error appears when we use bang(!) operator with the nullable variable but i don't know how to fix this. As in my code i am getting this issue in this line where i am getting the email of a user in firebase

```
String? get user => _firebaseUser.value!.email;
```

and i am using this value in other dart file where i am checking that if user is null then go to the login page but if user is not null than i want to keep user signed in.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx((){
      return Get.find<FirebaseController>().user!=null ? MainPage() : LoginPage();
    });
  }
```

how to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

use this instead:

```dart
String? get user => _firebaseUser.value?.email;
```

your `value` may be null so you can't use `!` for it. the above code returns null if the `_firebaseUser.value` is null, otherwise returns `_firebaseUser.value.email`

Comment: i also did this but when i login then email is not reteriving and i am getting message that null value is returning instead of email

Comment: probably there is a problem with your firebase configuration. but the correct approach to use email is this.

Comment: actually i was doing a silly mistake i.e i was not assigning controllers in textfformfields that's why i was getting getting null